Modify Free / Busy in an Google Calendar Event with Google apps script doesn't work
I'm trying to change the visibility detail of an event in my "primary" calendar from Busy to Free for some events... this doesn't fail BUT this doesn't work.
**To recrate: **

In your calendar, create an event (i.e. meeting) with visibility details in "Busy".
Create a standalone script with the function and play.

This will get events for one day and will try to change "Busy" to "Free".
function test(){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var startTime = new Date();
  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setDate(endTime.getDate() + 1);

  var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);

  // Itera sobre cada evento encontrado.
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var eventTitle = event.getTitle();
    var eventType = event.getEventType()
    var calendarId = calendar.getId();
    var eventIdOriginal = event.getId();
    var eventId = eventIdOriginal.replace("@google.com","");      
    let originalEvent = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);

    //1. first try
    originalEvent.transparency = "transparent";

    //2. second try
    var changes = { transparency: "transparent" };
    try{
      //Calendar.Events.update(originalEvent, calendarId, eventId,changes);
      Calendar.Events.patch(changes,calendarId, eventId);
    }catch(e){
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }

}

this don't generate any exception BUT this doesn't work. The event continue like "Busy".
Visibility detail en Google Calendar Event
I want this because I want to customize my availability time to share my calendar to another teams.
I tried to change other properties like color and this works fine.
Can u help me ?
I need to change the visibility detail from busy to free. it's all.
I'm in a business account.

From what I understand, what you'd like to do is change the status of events that were already created in the primary calendar from Busy to Free.
Here's a modified version of your code to help you start that achieves what you'd like:
function test() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var calendarId = calendar.getId();
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  var event = events.map(e => e.getId().replace("@google.com", ""));
  var changes = {
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
  event.forEach(id => {
    Calendar.Events.patch(changes, calendarId, id);
  });
}

OUTPUT



Note: The script changes all events' status from Busy to Free. If you wish to do it for let's say the first event, you may use:

function test() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var calendarId = calendar.getId();
  var startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  var endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  var event = events.map(e => e.getId().replace("@google.com", ""));
  var changes = {
    transparency: "transparent"
  };
  Calendar.Events.patch(changes, calendarId, event[0]);
}

OUTPUT



To do it for some events, you may add a condition to which ones it would work.

REFERENCES

Array.prototype.map()
Array.prototype.forEach()


Can you confirm this was able to address your question, @Hernán Fúquene?
